# Container won't connect to network Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am trying to set up my docker-compose with Kafka, and have containers communicate through it. While trying to connect containers over shared networks, one of my containers can't seem to connect to Kafka, while the other can.

Said container returns NoBrookersAvailable error. I tried to use `docker networks inspect` on the network and I saw that it is not connected while the other containers are.

What am I doing wrong?

The container is the password_module.

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.3"
services:

  controller_module:
    image: controller_module:latest
    networks:
      - password_network
      - analyze_network
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - kafka

  analyze_module:
    image: analyze_module:latest
    networks:
      - analyze_network
    volumes:
      - /kamuti:/testdir
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - kafka

  password_module:
    image: password_module:latest
    networks:
      - password_network
    volumes:
      - /kamuti:/testdir
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka
    networks:
      - password_network
      - analyze_network
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=172.17.0.1
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS= find-password:1:1, password:1:1, analyze-folder:1:1, folder-data:1:1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    networks:
      - password_network
      - analyze_network
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=zookeeper
      
#volumes:
#  - #TODO
networks:
  password_network:
    external: true
  analyze_network:
    external: true
```

The results of `docker network inspect -f '{{range .Containers}}{{.Name}} {{end}}' password_network`:
`homeassignment_zookeeper_1 homeassignment_password_module_1 kafka homeassignment_controller_module_1`

Comment: Where did you find `172.17.0.1`? Is this address the same in **both** networks Kafka is attached to? What specific address are your clients using? Why aren't you using the `HOSTNAME_COMMAND` mentioned in the documentation? Or, did you read https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/wiki/Connectivity Also, unclear why Zookeeper has a Kafka environment variable

Comment: I suggest to use `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://kafka:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092` environment variable in `kafka` service. The services running inside the containers should connect to `kafka:29092` while service which runs on the host itself should connect to `localhost:9092` address. If you want to understand why read this [article](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/)